# How to split prefix and suffix in python?

Tags: python, unix, nlp

I have a big text file that contains an input list like in the table below. What I need is to separate it into the different columns (to prefix, root, and suffix). They have `-` and `#` between them. I need a formula to separate them by `-` and `#`; or if there is a slash `/`, it should take the first part and ignore the word after the slash; or if the word is inside `{}` it should ignore it as well.

```
Input             Output
form              prefix        root         suffix    
----------        -------       -------      -------
jalan                           jalan
ba-jalan          ba            jalan
pem-porut#an      pem           porut        an
daun #kulu                      daun         kulu
daun#kulu                       daun         kulu
tarik-napas       tarik         napas
tarik#napas                     tarik        napas
n-cium #bo        n             cium         bow
arau/araw                       arau
imbaw//nimbaw                   imbaw
dengo | nengo                   dengo
dodop=am                        dodop        am
{di} dalam                      dalam
di {dalam}                      di
```

Comment: Can we see the code you've tried?

Comment: @erip I have tried too much and used my codes but couldn't do it. I stack how to write a code for it.

Comment: Please provide text as text, not as an image. Images can't be copy/pasted for experimentation; people who would otherwise try to help you will be discouraged by the need to retype your test data themselves. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: This looks like you are doing morphological analysis so I added the [tag:nlp] tag.

Comment: If you can't *replace* the image with something more useful, please don't edit it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rough approximation of what you seem to be asking, using regular expressions by way of the Python `re` library.

```py
import re

m = re.match(r'(?:\{[^-#{}/]+\})?(?:([^-#{}/]+)-)?([^-#{}/]+)(?:/[^-#{}/]+)?(?:#([^-#{}/]+))?', word)
if m:
    prefix, root, suffix = m.groups()
```

Your examples also seem to have `=` and `|` as separators, but extending this to allow for those as well should be relatively straightforward once you understand how this is working.

In brief, `re.match()` returns `False` if the regex doesn't match, and otherwise, it returns a match object whose `.groups()` method contains the text which matched the grouping parentheses in the regular expression. `(?:...)` parentheses are non-grouping, parentheses without `?:` immediately after the opening parenthesis capture into a group.

The expression can be divided into the following:

- `(?:\{[^-#{}/]+\})?` - non-grouping expression to skip anything in `{braces}`
- `(?:([^-#{}/]+)-)?` - non-grouping wrapper around a grouping expression for anything before a dash `-`
- `([^-#{}/]+)` - main root - grouping expression to capture text which doesn't match one of the delimiters
- `(?:/[^-#{}/]+)?` - non-grouping expression to ignore anything after a slash
- `(?:#([^-#{}/]+))?` - similar to the dash, capture any suffix after `#`, with a non-grouping wrapper around the whole group and then a grouping capture for the text after the delimiter

This will seem intimidating at first, but once you have deciphered the first couple, you should understand how they all work.  In some more detail, let's examine the dash expression.

- `(?:` - we need a non-capturing group to mark all of this as optional, down at the end
- `(` - capture any matching text between the grouping parentheses into a `.group()`
- `[^-#{}/]` - match a single character which is not `-` or `#` or `{` or `}` or `/`
- `+` - actually, one or more of the previous, as many as possible
- `)` - end of capture
- `-` - as long as all of this ends in a literal dash `-`
- `)?` - all of this is optional; if skipping this will allow the overall expression to match, the regex engine will (but it will still prefer to match, if possible - this is called "greedy matching").

Notice how `[^-#{}/]+` keeps appearing in all of these groups. We don't want to allow the text we capture to match one of the delimiters.

You don't specify what to do with spaces so this simply regards them as any other character. Perhaps you want to keep them out of groups when they are adjacent to a delimiter, too?

Demo: https://ideone.com/GeDntG

Comment: I don't how to deal with one **'dengo | nengo'** the output must be one of them.  Thank you

Comment: If there could be both `|` and `/` the rule needs to have them in the right order. If `|` can come after `/` then just tack on another group with that separator; it should not be hard to see how to add it. If `|` is more like a synonym to `/` you can just update the rule to have `[/|]` instead if plain `/` as its separator. Either way, you'll want to update the other groups to have `[^-#{}/|]` instead of just `[^-#{}/]`

Comment: If you still need more help, post a new question. This time, take care to review the guidance for [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [mre]. Because your rules potentially overlap, explain how they interact (just like in real morphology) or explain why they don't. Feel free to ping me here with a link.

Comment: Araman left a comment in ** Answer section** I didn't get it. please look at it. thanks.